# What would you call the opposite of a "bandwagon jumper?"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

I'm looking for a word or phrase to succinctly describe someone who prefers to follow unpopular causes.

Comment: Hi, welcome to ELU! Can you add a bit more information, especially what words you have considered and why you've rejected them? Questions here are meant to be as well-developed as possible. Cheers!

Comment: Do not post suggestions as comments. Answers go in the answer box.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could perhaps use the word *contrarian*:

> **contrarian**, *noun*: a person who takes a contrary position or attitude ([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/contrarian))

More specifically:

> **contrarian**, *noun*: someone such as a writer or politician who likes to disagree with other people and express opinions that are unpopular ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/contrarian))

There is also the word '[maverick](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/maverick),' which has many definitions that sort of touch on your description, although whether it fits your purposes exactly I'm not sure.

Comment: Thanks! I was looking for just this: something with a mildly negative connotation, like "bandwagon jumper."

Answer (score 5):

Consider ***counterculturalist**, **hipster**, or **bohemian**.*
From Wiktionary:

- > **[counterculture](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/counterculture)**
  >
  > 1. Any culture whose values and lifestyles are opposed to those of the established mainstream culture, especially to western culture.
- > **[counterculturalist](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/counterculturalist)**
  >
  > 1. One who engages in counterculture.
- > **[hipster](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hipster)**
  >
  > 2. A member of Bohemian counterculture.
- > [**bohemian**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Bohemian)
  >
  > 3. someone known for flouting social conventions, especially someone involved in the arts.

Answer (score 4):

**Maverick** is one possibility.

Per *Merriam-Webster*, the word means

> an independent individual who does not go along with a group or party

Comment: Hmm... I think a "maverick" is more someone who does their own thing *regardless* of the group, rather than *because* they're actively avoiding following the group

Answer (score 1):

"Devil's advocate" may carry part of the meaning you intend to convey.

> One who argues against a cause or position, not as a committed opponent but simply for the sake of argument or to determine the validity of the cause or position.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply mean someone who does *not* rush to follow the latest trends (as opposed to one who actively seeks out something else), then perhaps:

- [stick-in-the-mud](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/stick-in-the-mud)
- [(old) fogey](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/old_fogey)
- [dyed-in-the-wool](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dyed-in-the-wool)
- [footdragger](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/footdragger#English)
- [fuddy-duddy](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fuddy-duddy)

…all of which refer to one who is unwilling to change, set in their ways, old-fashioned, unprogressive, and/or resistant to change.